# MySQL server uses only 1 out of 48 CPU cores with GROUP BY queries

Tags: mysql, multithreading, performance, group-by

I have high end 48 CPU core server with latest MySQL 5.7 installed

I'm bit surprised that when executing queries with GROUP BY, no matter how I format my query I get only 1 CPU core used for that query, clearly illustrated by htop output

Of course I can perform multiple queries at the same time, and that's how I can use all the cores but it seems not too convenient and not every query can be split to use full server's power

Are there any MySQL extensions or SQL hints that allow to use multiple cores while processing data with GROUP BY?

Comment: which engine are you using? as far as i know, only innoDB fully supports mutlicore cpu

Comment: MySQL (currently) doesn't support multiple cores for one query.

Comment: @Christian Felix: I use InnoDB engine

Comment: @Solarflare could you provide some link to the documentation where you found this info?

Comment: @Matthias If you know that beforehand, you can find it at [How MySQL Uses Threads for Client Connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-threads.html). One thread per connection, and thus one thread per query (apart from disk access). It doesn't explicitly say it won't create additional threads for a query, but it probably should if it would support this, so the only other indication is that this information isn't there. But it's harder to show that something isn't (anywhere) in the documentation than that it is.

Answer (score 12):

As the accepted answer by RolandoMySQLDBA to [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core) question says:

> I actually discussed innodb_thread_concurrency with a MySQL Expert at
> the Percona Live NYC conference back in May 2011.
>
> I learned something surprising: In spite of the documentation, it is
> best to leave innodb_thread_concurrency at 0 (infinite concurrency).
> That way, InnoDB decides the best number of innodb_concurrency_tickets
> to open for a given MySQL instance setup.
>
> Once you set innodb_thread_concurrency to 0, you can set
> innodb_read_io_threads and innodb_write_io_threads (both since MySQL
> 5.1.38) to the maximum value of 64. This should engage more cores.

This is the best guidance I ever found on how to make MySQL use more cores **in general**.

Comment: Did you test this suggestion with actual queries and confirmed, that after using this settings you can use more than one core for one SQL query?

Comment: Yes, I did. However, I emphasised the expression **in general**. It does not mean that a specific query at a given point of time will definitely use multiple cores.

Comment: set global innodb_read_io_threads = 8 Error Code: 1238. Variable 'innodb_read_io_threads' is a read only variable

Comment: @weefwefwqg3 it's not a dynamic variable, place it to config file(my.cnf) or your custom(if any)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from background threads, one connection will use only one CPU core.  The applies to `GROUP BY`, `UNION`, `PARTITION`, and anything else you might think it should manage to do in parallel.

The statement applies for InnoDB at least through MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2.

A third-party software can make use of multiple cores:  https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/01/parallel-query-mysql-shard-query/  .

Also, the "column store" in MariaDB 10.2 probably uses multiple cores.